# Can we use the inverse quadratic interpolation for this equation's non-real roots with these points?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

$$f(x)=x^4+2x^3+5x^2+5x-3=0$$

I've chosen these values as guessed values: $$(x,f(x)) --> (-1+4i, 172+116i), (1+2i, -42+2i), (-3+i, 14-69i)$$

Am I doing something wrong or can't we obtain a non-real root with these starting points? What am I missing or what's the problem with these points?

Comment: Could you add a link to "inverse quadratic interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse quadratic iteration was intended to be an improvement of the secant root computation in the secant method, regula falsi, first Dekker method, using a third point to somewhat capture the curvature of the function and thus get closer root approximations. Thus quadratic in the regular sense in Muller's method, inverse quadratic in Dekker's and Brent's method, also hyperbolic curves were explored by them, exponential approximation in Ridders method.

Conceptually, this works best, or only, if a root  guaranteed to be inside or close to the convex hull of the 3 sampling points, so that the function approximation is more interpolation than extrapolation. It also helps if the function is almost linear in this region. In the real methods, a bracketing interval (Dekker, Brent) is such a root guarantee. Outside this set, the inverse quadratic and the original polynomial function will be wildly different, so that the value at zero of the inverse quadratic has little to no relationship to any root of the original function.

---

The inverse quadratic iteration can be realized in python as

```
def f(z): return np.polyval([1,2,5,5,-3],z)

def invquad(z,w): 
    def term(i,j,k): return z[i]*w[j]*w[k]/(w[i]-w[j])/(w[i]-w[k])
    return term(0,1,2)+term(1,2,0)+term(2,1,0)

def invquaditer(z1,z2,z3):
     z = [z1,z2,z3]
     w = [ f(zz) for zz in z ]
     for zz,ww in zip(z,w): print(f"     z = {zz:30.12f},  f(z) = {ww:30.12g}")
     for k in range(30):
         zz = invquad(z[-3:],w[-3:])
         z.append(zz);
         w.append(f(zz));
         if k%5==4: print(f"{k+1:3}: z = {z[-1]: 30.12f},  f(z) = {w[-1]: 30.12g}")

invquaditer(-1+4j,1+2j,-3+1j)
```

with the (shortened) result

```
     z = -1.000000000000+4.000000000000j,  f(z) =                       172+116j
     z =  1.000000000000+2.000000000000j,  f(z) =                         -42+2j
     z = -3.000000000000+1.000000000000j,  f(z) =                         14-69j
  5: z =  4.317538320268+0.091310253210j,  f(z) =   619.062884775+43.9929910763j
 10: z =  2.611476826121-0.559031334510j,  f(z) =   107.136336831-77.9195795091j
 15: z =  0.555953546644-0.631985686099j,  f(z) =  -2.14611625211-7.21371931414j
 20: z =  0.404523365865-0.000009492569j,  f(z) = -1.79088680259e-05-9.76961198257e-05j
 25: z =  0.404525105890-0.000000000000j,  f(z) =           0-2.85657089322e-16j
 30: z =  0.404525105890+0.000000000000j,  f(z) = -1.37667655054e-14+4.57051342915e-15j
```

It is visible that the iteration first moves chaotically away from the starting points. Apparently the iterations for all permutations of the initial points converge to the same real root, which could mean that this root has the largest basin of attraction, or it could just be a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are speaking about Brent's method.

For the present case, the process seems to diverge quite fast. Hoping no mistake in my coding, the first iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_n & f(x_n) \\
 1 & -1+4  \,i & 172+116 \,i \\
 2 & 1+2 \,i & -42+2 \,i \\
 3 & -3+ \,i & 14-69 \,i \\
 4 & -0.233501+0.851131 \,i & -6.23677+1.84608 \,i \\
 5 & -0.445646+0.740844 \,i & -6.00227+0.934791 \,i \\
 6 & -0.444457-0.750972 \,i & -6.0374-0.949373 \,i \\
 7 & 1.52232 +10.0378 \,i & 7355.74 -7697.24 \,i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Changing the values of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ the process does converge
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_n & f(x_n) \\
 1 & -0.5+ \,i & -6.9375+ \,i \\
 2 & -0.5+2 \,i & -2.4375+2 \,i \\
 3 & -0.5+3 \,i & 45.0625 +3 \,i \\
 4 & -0.0363912+2.38487 \,i & 1.93196 -14.0789\, i \\
 5 & -0.451927+2.10997 \,i & -0.204939+1.01463 \,i \\
 6 & -0.420599+2.12696 \,i & 0.125128 +0.257341\, i \\
 7 & -0.409254+2.12283\, i & -0.0052756+0.00522175 \,i \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

As you can see, even when it works, the path to the solution is really chaotic.

I should not recommend to use Brent's mathod for complex roots except if you have very good points to start with and this is very difficult in the complex domain.

For comparison, let us try Newton method
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n  \\
 0 & -1+4 \,i \\
 1 & -0.836181+3.13317 \,i \\
 2 & -0.687862+2.54836 \,i \\
 3 & -0.543257+2.21764 \,i \\
 4 & -0.432473+2.11769 \,i \\
 5 & -0.408802+2.12256 \,i \\
 6 & -0.409065+2.12308 \,i 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: The first iteration also converges, to $0.4045251058900...$ after ca. 25 steps, and by the formulation of the question and trying with the second and third point switched, also for all permutations of these points. I'm not sure that there is a deeper reason for that specific behavior.

Comment: Did you use Brent's method or is it inverse quadratic interpolation. As far as I know inverse quadratic interpolation is used in Brent's method but I don't mean to use it in Brent's method, I want to use it alone.

Comment: By the way, the value $−0.451927+2.10997i$ you get on n=5 for the inverse quadratic interpolation's table is different from mine. I obtain $x_5 = -0.0083869 + 2.184768i$. Could you please check the value you obtained? I can't find what I am missing if it's because of my calculations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could you please share with me what you use to check its convegence to the root? I do it on my own :/ Is there a free application for this, or a site?

Comment: I just did 30 iterations of the inverse quadratic iteration, taking the last 3 points for the interpolation. It is a short 20 lines python script, so yes, it is a free application. // For the starting values in the second run I also get `-0.4519268282468675 + 2.1099684811087487j`, so if you did something different from pure inverse quadratic iteration, please add the precise method and one example run to your question.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks Sir! I just realised that I eliminated the $x_3$ after obtaining $x_4$. I did so because it's further to function's zero than $x_1$. I thought this would make it converge faster. Why doesn't it happen as I expected?

Comment: @Mathrix : If you just did it the once, then that amounts to a permutation of the initial values, using instead of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ the start $x_3,x_2,x_1$. This also converges to the same real root. // If you do this in every step, then this is a "non-linear" variant of the iteration, to always replace the point with the largest function value. While you get a guaranteed descent, the iteration might stall or cycle at some point that is not a root.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I didn't really understand the reason why it may stall or cycle. Could you please explain? How can we know which value to eliminate then?

Comment: @LutzLehmann And when I used those points I mentioned in the question in Muller's method, it gave me the exact root I was looking for. What should we deduce from this? Muller's method is much more reliable than the inverse quadratic interpolation?

Comment: @Mathrix : You should put that as a new question (and generally put comments, from the 4th on, below the more appropriate answer). Both why Muller's method seems more stable and how one could modify the inverse quadratic iteration over the complex domain into some kind of trust-region method. There are no short answers to questions about global convergence, even if local convergence is guaranteed.